# Fileupload Closest tr in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="file"  /> </td>
         <td> <input type="button" id="btn"  /> </td>      
   </tr>        
    <tr>
    <td> <input type="file"  /> </td>
          <td> <input type="button" id="btn"  /> </td>      
   </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <input type="file" /> </td>
          <td> <input type="button" id="btn"  /> </td>    
   </tr>

</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
  var formData = new FormData();
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var fup = $(tr).find("input[type='file']");
  var totalFiles = fup.length;//Here, getting total file count
  for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
       var file = fup.file[i];//I am getting exception here
       formData.append("fupUpdate", file);
       }
```

I am unable to get the list of  files appended to formdata.

```
Error Message: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
```

Please assist me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
var fData = new FormData();
var tr = $('table').closest('tr');
var fup = $('tr').find("input[type='file']");
var totalFiles = fup.length;//Here, getting total file count
  for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
       var file = fup[i].files[0];//Exception will not occur here
       console.log(file)
       fData.append("fupUpdate", file);
   }
```

Do not create local variable with the same name as FormData

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right just replace

```
var file = fup.file[i];//I am getting exception here
```

with

```
var file = fup[i].files[0];// no Exception here.
```

and this will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with your selection of the inputs. You can use of the following options:

```
$(":file")
```

Or

```
$("table tr :input[type='file']").each(function (i,v) {
      var file=$(v);
      //Your code goes here
});
```

Working example [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myx87ov5/2/)